# how to send the image type,name and size using $.post

Tags: php, image

**form.php**

```
 <form name="frm1" action="3.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <div class="upload">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="r" value="father" id="r">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$id?>" id="r1">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?=$a?>" id="r2">
                                    <input type="file" name="uploadPic"  id="upload" />
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

**pop.js**

```
  $(".upload").on("click", function () {
    console.log("page");
    $(".upload").on("change", function () {

     var fr =$("#r").val();
     var fr1 =$("#r1").val();
     var fr2 =$("#r2").val();
     var fr3 =$("#upload").val();
     //console.log("page"+fr+fr1+fr2+fr3);
     $.post("upload.php", {
            "pic": fr3}, function (data) {
                    console.log(eval(data));
                    if (data.result == "1") {
                        console.log("getresult");
                        //webpopup();

                    } else {
                        alert("Please try again.");
                    }
                }, "json");


      });     
    });
```

i want to send the whole image as input file using $.POST . but i am only able to send the name of the image . how to the whole image .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

If you upload something via HTML, you can access it in PHP with $_FILES.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $dir . "/" . $filename);
```

With this code, you can move the uploaded file into every directory you want and then access it with your browser or load it into a form.

Comment: without refreshing the page i want to send the images

Comment: PHP is only usable before the page is finished with loading. You cant use it after, maybe you should take a look at jQuery and AJAX.

Comment: can u explain me some example

Comment: Unfortunally not, im not rly familiar with AJAX and jQuery. Try to open another question and tag it with AJAX and jQuery, then more ppl which mgiht be able to help you will find the question.